# Updating date column 9999 instead of 1999

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update column with Date as `01-DEC-99` but oracle consider `99` as `1999` but I need `9999` to update.

script:

```
update table_name 
set column_name = '01-DEC-99' 
where condition.
```

I am expecting `9999` in date column.

Comment: Btw. the maximum date for the DATE type is December 31, 9999 AD in Oracle. See: [SQL Language Reference
 / Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html).

Comment: Why do you use year 9999? Consider to use `NULL` for such data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `NULL` can have semantic meaning as an unknown value or the column may be non-`NULL`. So it may not always be appropriate to use `NULL` as a default value.

Comment: @MT0 I am quite sure, year 9999 means something like "undefined" nor "not valid". Thus `NULL` might be an option.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `date '9999-12-31'` may be used in validity intervals and generally means date infinity. It is very useful for uniform filtering (`some_datw between datefrom and dateto`) and indexing/partitioning without extra effort.

Answer (score 3):

`'01-DEC-99'` is not a `DATE` is it a string literal that happens to look like a date. Oracle will try and be helpful and implicitly convert it to a `DATE` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

What you should do is **NEVER** rely on implicit conversion between data types:

1. Use a `DATE` literal, which is always specified in `YYYY-MM-DD` format:

   ```sql
   UPDATE table_name 
   SET   column_name = DATE '9999-12-01' 
   WHERE condition
   ```
2. Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal, which is always specified in `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format:

   ```sql
   UPDATE table_name 
   SET   column_name = TIMESTAMP '9999-12-01 00:00:00' 
   WHERE condition
   ```
3. Use `TO_DATE` with an explicit format model and a 4-digit year:

   ```sql
   UPDATE table_name 
   SET   column_name = TO_DATE('01-DEC-9999', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') 
   WHERE condition
   ```
4. **DO NOT USE THIS OPTION**

   Out of completeness, if you are going to rely on implicit conversions then set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='English';
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY';

   UPDATE table_name 
   SET   column_name = '01-DEC-9999' 
   WHERE condition
   ```

   *(This will affect all future implicit conversions within the session and any user can change their own NLS session parameters at any time so you should never rely on them being set to one particular value. Instead you should use one of the first three options.)*

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to the following

```
update table_name 
set column_name = DATE '9999-12-01' 
where condition.
```

Comment: This relies on an implicit conversion from string-to-date. If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match then the conversion will fail without changing the text of the query. (Or worse, if the format matches sufficiently for the conversion to happen you may find that the date is not what you expect. I.e. `'01-DEC-2023'` could be parsed as `2023-12-01 00:00:00` or it could be parsed as `0001-12-20 23:00:00` depending on the implicit format model - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9mcUApVz)). You should never rely on implicit conversions.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for your comment as I wasn't aware of that! Is my updated answer better?